# How to automate the installation of loopback adapter on windows 7

Tags: networking, window, loopback, stunnel

I am working on a software which requires loopback adapter. I would like to automate installation of loopback adapter through batch scripts.

Please let me know the best way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: devcon -r install %WINDIR%\Inf\Netloop.inf *MSLOOP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be simply done by using devcon utility.

go to the command prompt and run the below command and loopback adapter will get installed.

devcon -r install %WINDIR%\Inf\Netloop.inf *MSLOOP